# Python 3 : Print a list that's inside a list

Tags: python, list, printing

I cannot seem to print a list that's within a list. I know that it goes wrong when I repeat the for loop for key and values. I was wondering if there is a way to make so that it prints each troop name for each platoon.

```
import random, math
first_name = ['John', 'Clay', 'Gordy', 'Erv', 'Sebastian', 'Tilly', 'Jesse', 'Alban', 'Oliver', 'Samuel', 'Joseph', 'Gregory', 'Alair', 'Gilbert', 'Nigel', 'Gibson', 'Oliver', 'Ralph', 'Rufus', 'Garson', 'Ferrol', 'Miles', 'Chilton', 'Charles', 'Gordon', 'Edward', 'Gerald', 'Shel', 'Dean', 'Noah', 'Herbert', 'Humphrey', 'Hanley', 'Ruben', 'Gibson', 'Jonathan', 'Fisk', 'Harold', 'Cristian', 'Andy', 'Kyne', 'Garson', 'Jackson', 'Maitland', 'George', 'Ford', 'Raleigh', 'Fox', 'Forbes', 'Yeardleigh', 'Gordon', 'Francis', 'Jett', 'Fairfax', 'Ford', 'Haines', 'Benjamin', 'Samuel', 'Alban', 'Chip', 'Eric', 'Alban', 'Charles', 'Sherman', 'Harrison', 'Malcolm', 'Chilton', 'Eliah', 'Junior', 'Mark', 'Bond', 'Chick', 'Emmanuel', 'Raleigh', 'Brigham', 'Archibald', 'Gates', 'Filbert', 'Barnabas', 'Geoffrey', 'Terence', 'Stacy', 'Forbes', 'Gomer', 'Fairly', 'Archer', 'Oscar', 'William', 'Ernes', 'Chill', 'Gregory', 'Weylin', 'Holt', 'Clayland', 'Gram', 'Forbes', 'Set', 'Hartwell', 'Luke', 'Garson']
last_name = ['Mitchell', 'Martin', 'Anderson', 'Patel', 'Young', 'Jackson', 'Ward', 'Jackson', 'Patel', 'Walker', 'Lee', 'Patel', 'Johnson', 'Thomas', 'Morris', 'Watson', 'Martin', 'Roberts', 'Jones', 'Lewis', 'Morgan', 'Wood', 'Lee', 'White', 'James', 'Scott', 'Young', 'Clarke', 'Edwards', 'Smith', 'Jackson', 'Turner', 'Ward', 'Hall', 'Anderson', 'Walker', 'Scott', 'Mitchell', 'Williams', 'Young', 'Allen', 'Huges', 'Phillips', 'Robinson', 'Evans', 'Thomas', 'Taylor', 'Robinson', 'Harris', 'Ward', 'Johnson', 'Anderson', 'Scott', 'Martin', 'Allen', 'Clark', 'Jones', 'Wilson', 'Phillips', 'Lewis', 'Jones', 'Anderson', 'Wright', 'Clark', 'White', 'Lewis', 'Patel', 'Wilson', 'Wilson', 'Taylor', 'Williams', 'Turner', 'Smith', 'Davies', 'Harrison', 'Thompson', 'Anderson', 'Harris', 'Brown', 'Lewis', 'Phillips', 'Watson', 'Harrison', 'Harris', 'Wilson', 'Davies', 'Brown', 'Huges', 'Parker', 'King', 'Wright', 'Anderson', 'Anderson', 'Phillips', 'Harrison', 'Walker', 'Wood', 'Young', 'Clark', 'Jones']
troops = []
temp_platoon = []
platoons = []
platoon_names = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India', 'Juliet', 'Kilo', 'Lima', 'Mike', 'November', 'Oscar', 'Papa', 'Quebec', 'Romeo', 'Sierra', 'Tango', 'Uniform', 'Victor', 'Whiskey', 'X-Ray', 'Yankee', 'Zulu']
a = 0
while a < 90:
    s_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + random.choice(last_name)
    s_number = 100
    troops.append((s_name, s_number))
    a = a + 1


platoon_number = 1
troop_number = 0
for key in troops :
    troop_number = troop_number + 1
    a = troops.pop(0)
    temp_platoon.append((a))

    if troop_number == 30:
        # Platoon n is the name of  platoon
        # Platoon is the actual platoon
        platoon_number = platoon_number + 1
        platoon = platoon_names.pop(0)
        platoon_n = platoon
        platoon = []
        for k, v in temp_platoon:
            platoon.append((k, v)) 
            print("Added {} to platoon {}. He has {} health".format(k, platoon_n, v))
        platoons.append((platoon_n))
        troop_number = 0

def read ():
    print("Reading")
    for key in platoons:
        print(key)
        for w in key:
            print(w)
        print(platoons)

read()
```

Also note im teaching myself python 3. I have only just started touching on classes.

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Where do you have a list within a list? Where are you printing it? Try to post a minimal-length program that shows the issue.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I can't tell when Class Platoon begins and when it ends.

Comment: Also...I don't know if you did this on purpose or what..but your Platoon class should have an `__init__` function. That way you don't have to call `p.create()` after creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I may have it wrong, but I think you might want it to look something like this:

```
import random
first_name = ['John', 'Clay', 'Gordy', 'Erv']
last_name = ['Mitchell', 'Martin', 'Anderson', 'Patel']
platoon_names = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Delta']
platoons = dict()
```

using a list comprehension we can completely replace the while loop. every soldier is a tuple (name, health)... I presume you wanted this, but if not just remove the 100).

```
troops = [(random.choice(first_name) + " " + random.choice(last_name), 100) for r in range(90)]
```

the following helper function is lifter from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

we now populate the platoons dictionary (the key is the platoon name, while the value is a list containing the soldiers).

```
for number, platoon in enumerate(list(chunks(troops,3))):
    platoons[platoon_names[number]] = platoon
```

use iteritems to iterate over a dictionary.

```
def read ():
    print("Reading")
    for platoon, troops in platoons.iteritems():
        print("--------Platoon name--------")
        print(platoon)
        print("--------troops--------")
        for (name, health) in troops:
            print(name)
```

and this is what we get.

```
>>> read()
Reading
--------Platoon name--------
Alpha
--------troops--------
John Anderson
Clay Mitchell
Erv Martin
--------Platoon name--------
Beta
--------troops--------
Clay Anderson
Clay Anderson
Clay Patel
--------Platoon name--------
Delta
--------troops--------
John Anderson
Gordy Martin
John Anderson
--------Platoon name--------
Charlie
--------troops--------
Clay Mitchell
Clay Patel
Clay Patel
>>>
```